# Symfony: FormType, Entity, queryBuilder - how change the value of generated options?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

I'd like to add the field `country` *(string)* to my `Form\Type`.

`country` is not related to `Entity\Country`, and should store country-codes *(en, it, fr, ...)* instead of the entity's ID.

I load the country codes of `Entity\Country` to my form, but the generated select has the entity's ID as the value, the `__toString()`-return as text.

How can I set `c.code` as the `<option>`s value?

**FormType:**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('country', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'appBundle:Country',
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')->orderBy('c.code', 'ASC');
        }
    ));
}
```

**Generated select:**

```
<select>
    <option value="1">en</option>
    <option value="2">it</option>
    <option value="3">fr</option>
</select>
```

**Desired select:**

```
<select>
    <option value="en">en</option>
    <option value="it">it</option>
    <option value="fr">fr</option>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Data transformers (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) might help though I think it would be less confusing to just use a regular choice list and not the entity type.  Make a custom CountryFormType and have it query the country codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using symfony 2.7, use the `choice_label` option of the `entity` form field type. If using an older version of symfony, use the `property` option. More information here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Comment: `This is the property that should be used for displaying the entities as text in the HTML element. If left blank, the entity object will be cast into a string and so must have a __toString() method.` That is not what @Mr. B. is asking. 

He wants the option values to be associated with another property of the entity and not the Id

Answer (score 0):

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('country', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'appBundle:Country',
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')->orderBy('c.code', 'ASC');
        },
        'choice_value'=>"country-code", //(country-code = column name in database)
        'choice_label'=>"country-name"
    ));
}
```